# Django CMS Unknown column 'djangocms_picture_picture.use_responsive_image' in 'field list

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-cms

Please find below the complete traceback.
This is happening when am trying to publish a page via django cms portal.
Have tried doing migration: 
python manage.py  migrate djangocms_picture
but its not working.

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 132, in get_response
>         response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 110, in _wrapped_view
>         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py",
> line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
>         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py",
> line 233, in inner
>         return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 34, in _wrapper
>         return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py",
> line 45, in inner
>         return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 30, in bound_func
>         return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 145, in inner
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line
> 1091, in publish_page
>         all_published = page.publish(language)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line
> 926, in publish
>         self._copy_contents(public_page, language)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line
> 562, in _copy_contents
>         cleared_placeholders = target._clear_placeholders(language)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line
> 554, in _clear_placeholders
>         models.query.QuerySet.delete(plugins)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 536, in delete
>         collector.collect(del_query)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py",
> line 228, in collect
>         elif sub_objs:
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 170, in __nonzero__
>         return type(self).__bool__(self)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 166, in __bool__
>         self._fetch_all()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 965, in _fetch_all
>         self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 238, in iterator
>         results = compiler.execute_sql()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 840, in execute_sql
>         cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 64, in execute
>         return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98,
> in __exit__
>         six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 64, in execute
>         return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
> line 124, in execute
>         return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.74.0.54/newrelic/hooks/database_dbapi2.py",
> line 22, in execute
>         *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205,
> in execute
>         self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line
> 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>         raise errorclass, errorvalue
>     OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'djangocms_picture_picture.use_responsive_image' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: When you try makemigrations does it show that there are any migrations? Sounds like a column was deleted from the database but some of the objects still have that column in it

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue,

Its because of the django_cms libraries got updated in docker images on rebuild , as the exact version is not mentioned in dockerfile.So on any further builds takes the latest version from repository.This has lead to update. This update trigger the ORM models contradict with the table columns.

**Fix:**

Mentioned the actual versions of the package in dockerfile.

Before fix:

```
RUN pip install djangocms-link djangocms-file djangocms-picture djangocms-video djangocms-googlemap djangocms-snippet djangocms-style djangocms-column
```

After fix:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

requirements.txt
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.5.2
django-filer==1.3.2
django-formtools==2.1
django-mptt==0.8.7
django-polymorphic==1.3
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.10.0
django-treebeard==4.3
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.8
djangocms-attributes-field==0.3.0
djangocms-column==1.8.0
djangocms-file==2.0.2
djangocms-googlemap==1.1.1
djangocms-link==2.1.2
djangocms-picture==2.0.6
djangocms-snippet==2.0.0
djangocms-style==2.0.2
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.6.0
djangocms-video==2.0.4
```

This fixed the issue. 
Thanks!